# error: expected expression in list of expressions

Tags: swift

I am doing these little Swift assignments to get better at Swift and the code:

```
class StringCaterpillar {
    var bodyArray = ["h" , "e" , "l" , "l" , "o"]

    func add(_ text:String) {
        for text in 0...5 {
            print([text])
        }     // this is line 30
    }

    func go() {
        print(
    }
}
```

Has one error.
The error is, as you can tell:

> "playground:30:5: Error: expected expression in list of expressions.

Yes, I have not finished the 2nd function but I am just wondering if you guys could tell me where the error in this code is as well as what the overall concept of the error actually means.

Comment: When I copy and paste your code into a playground the error is on the incomplete `print(` line in the `go` function.

Comment: print() function, you forgot to close the bracket

Answer (score 1):

The best way to do it is:

```
class StringCaterpillar {
    var bodyArray = ["h" , "e" , "l" , "l" , "o"]

    func add(_ text:String) {
        for i in 0..<bodyArray.count {
            print(bodyArray[i])
        } 
    }

    func go() {
        print(
    }
}
```

In this way you'll never face issues when you add more items in the array.

Comment: An `for-each` would be the best way, but yeah, that is a nice blocker.

Comment: This answer has the same bad code in the `go` function.

Comment: The question is not about that function so its his duty to complete that function or delete that function. Same way you can also say there is no use of the parameter text in the function add but its his choice whatever he want to do with it. May be he want to do something with it.

Answer (score 0):

```
for text in 0...5 {
            print([text])
        }
```

This... I guess you want to print the place of the body array and you counted 5 objects in it?

If that is the case you should write:

```
for text in 0...4 {
                print(bodyArray[text])
            }
```

As you are only searching in an array without an name or something. You have ot call the name of the array.

Comment: `text` is not a good name for the variable representing an index.

Comment: Indeed it is not, but i'm following his code standard. I personally wouldn't even use a `for-loop` in this scenario

Answer (score 0):

```
class StringCaterpillar {
var bodyArray = ["h" , "e" , "l" , "l" , "o"]

func add(_ text:String) {
    // this loop is also wrong which make run time error your condition must be 
    // 0...4
// this is line 30**strong text**
   for i in 0...4 {
       print(bodyArray[i])
   }
}

func go() {
            // this is syntax error
    print() // there is a error you missed the bracket 
}
```

}

Answer (score 0):

You can use **foreach**

```
for text in bodyArray {
    print(text)
}
```

In this code , you try to reach bodyArray[5] but there is no index at 5